# call popup window from server side code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-2.0

I am trying to open a popup window from `load_page` event.  Why is it not working?

```
string popup = "<script language='javascript'>" +
   "window.open('" + "www.delfi.lt" + "', 'CustomPopUp, " +
   "'width=200, height=200, resizable=no')" +
   "</script>";
Page.RegisterStartupScript("Popup", popup);
```

Comment: Does it need to be server-side? Try putting the javascript directly in the ASPX file. If you need a little bit of server side code you can use the <#= #> tags in order to inject a little server-side logic.

Comment: Yes, I need in server side code, because letter it will be not in page_load event

Comment: Here's a link to serverside tags you can use http://forums.asp.net/p/1139381/1828702.aspx

Comment: Is the script in the actual html sent out? Is it just a javascript error - e.g. something like a missing `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. During the page lifecycle the entire page gets created on the server side and it's transmitted back to the client as HTML and javascript. So if your requirement is that the first time the page loads it shows the popup and thereafter on Post-back it doesn't?

Comment: Stuart was asking if the javascript is actually appearing in your page. Do view source and check. Nonetheless, there is an error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is wrong, you're missing a quote after CustomPopUp.

```
string popup = "<script language='javascript'>" +
       "window.open('" + "www.delfi.lt" + "', 'CustomPopUp', " +
       "'width=200, height=200, resizable=no');" +
       "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will block popups that aren't triggered by a user action, such as a click.  Popups on page load are especially likely to be ignored.